# wxPython Treebook Images

Tags: python, wxpython

In this official treebook tutorial they use the images module.  I can't find it.  Can someone give me a link or example how how to actually add things to the listbook?  I want to eventually display the filesystem folders there.

I can't find any information or examples, so a small one would help a lot.

Thanks

Comment: no one knows what you are talking about from this description perhaps PIL

Comment: tried PIL and Pillow in Python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about the Treebook example found here:  http://wiki.wxpython.org/Treebook

The zip for the entire source of those examples (including images.py) is on the author's blog:  http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/03/the-book-controls-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/3/

Comment: Here's the direct download to the source zip: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/Notebooks.zip